# Display "Test results" window during execution/debug in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Sorry for the lame question but this is driving me crazy.

How do you display the "Test Results" windows in Visual Studio 2010 while the unit tests are running ? Currently the window is displayed with the correct results **after execution**, but I would like to see it **during execution** so I can see the progression.

I used to have this working, but have reinstalled since, and it's not showing anymore.